# What are the tests performed by NASA's Mars rovers to establish that life could survive on the planet?

Tags: life, astrobiology

I am particularly interested in the Mars Rovers, which are out there trying to find life. Do they believe that the tests they perform are sufficient to verify the existence of life (*Also please mention about the tests*). How do they accommodate for the possibility of life forms different from the conventional carbon based as that of Earth?

I am really curious to get these answers, please explain.

Comment: You can check on NASAs website, as each mission has a page dedicated to it. If I remember correctly, I do not think that any of the rovers to date have technology to directly test for martian life forms. I think that the current missions are only able to test indirectly for conditions favorable to life and also possibly the evidence of organic molecules.

Comment: "How do they accommodate for the possibility of life forms different from the conventional carbon based as that of Earth?" - a very important question, *life* is just a human concept/definition applied to natural things, just like *species*. We could end up redefining life.

Comment: @rg255 I think that you need to remember that there are two things going for carbon as the basis of all organic life. The first is that it is the first element able to form 4 covalent bonds, which leads to the incredible diversity that we see in carbon-based molecules. Second, the second period elements are [more abundant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements) in the universe. There is still a good amount of silicon (The group four element below Carbon) but I would check the bond energies of silicon compounds and compare stability to their carbon counterpart.